# Querying Entity based on ElementCollection Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
public enum CarBrand {
    AUDI,
    VW,
    SEAT,
    SKODA
}

public class EquipmentItem extends BaseEntity { // ex. Blue color,
    @Column
    private String description; // Metalic blue

    @Column
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<CarBrand> carBrands;

    public void addBrand(CarBrand carBrand){
        this.carBrands.add(carBrand);
    }

    public void removeBrand(CarBrand carBrand){
        this.carBrands.remove(carBrand);
    }
```

I want to query *EquipmentItem* enity based on *carBrands* element collection contains a specific *CarBrand*. I want something like this:  **SELECT all equipmentItem WHERE carBrands contains "MyCarBrand"**
Is it possible somehow to add a new query  in EquipmentItemRepository?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `MEMBER OF` in the JPQL Query:

```
SELECT ei FROM EquipmentItem ei where 'MyCarBrand' MEMBER OF ei.carBrands
```